# Prove that a projective change of coordinates is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We define a projective coordinate change to be a map $\phi:P^n \to P^n$ given by $x \mapsto Ax$ where $A \in GL(n+1,k)$. How do you prove that this is an isomorphism, where by isomorphism I am referring to the definition on page 16 in Hartshorne's book "Algebraic Geometry", i.e a  morphism between two varieties which admits an inverse morphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That definition says that there must be a morphism $\psi:\mathbb P^n\to\mathbb P^n$ such that the two compositions $\phi\circ\psi$ and $\psi\circ\phi$ give the identities. The candidate is of course $\psi:x\mapsto A^{-1}x$, which verifies the definition of isomorphism.

So you only have to check that $\phi:x\mapsto Ax$ is a morphism. Note that $\phi$ is *linear*...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however how do you prove that $\phi$ is a closed map ?, as we need to check this in order to check that it and it's inverse map are morphisms.

Comment: It is easier to use the definition, I think. To be a morphism means: for every open subset $Y\subset\mathbb P^n$ and for every regular function $f:Y\to k$, the composition $f\circ \phi:\phi^{-1}(Y)\to k$ is a regular function. Regular function means: locally a quotient of two polynomials (with nonvanishing denominator).

Comment: This is just one of the two requirements for $\phi$ to be a morphism. You also need $\phi$ to be continous. So we should also show that $\phi$ is a closed map, as then both $\phi$ and the inverse will obviously be continous. But still thanks for helping out :)

Comment: You can check that $\phi$ is continuous as follows: take a principal open, say $U=D_+(T_0)\subset \mathbb P^n$, and show that $\phi^{-1}(U)=\{\alpha\in\mathbb P^n | A\cdot \alpha\in U \}$ is still open. It is equal to $D_+(h)$, with $h=\sum_{0\leq j\leq n}a_{0j}T_j$, where $(a_{00}\dots a_{0n})$ is the first row of $A$.

Comment: Is it all right now? :)

Comment: Not familiar with the $D_{+}(T_0)$ notation, however I can look into it myself when I have the time. I also seem to remember that a map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is a morphism iff it is locally of the form $\phi(b_o : \ldots b_n) = (F_0(b_0 \ldots b_n) ,\ldots F_m(b_0,\ldots b_n))$ where the $F_i$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree. Using this definition it is easy to show that the map defined above is a morphism.

Comment: Yes, it would be easier. I just wanted to check continuity directly, as you asked. And $D_+(T_0)$, which you may think of as $\{(1:a_1:\dots :a_n)\in\mathbb P^n | a_i\in k\}$, is just the complement of the hyperplane $V_+(T_0)=\{T_0=0\}$, exactly as $D_+(h)$ is the complement of the hypersurface $V_+(h)$. The $D_+(T_i)$ ($0\leq i\leq n$) form the standard affine covering of $\mathbb P^n$ (see e.g. Hartshorne). So, continuity + being locally a (linear) polynomial give you a morphism (without even assuming the result you mentioned).